# Why Create file in flow is much faster then Move file?

Tags: document-library, power-automate, move, create-document

When I move file within one Document library with Power Automate flow, it takes 7 seconds.

[image: Move]

The same operation using Get file content, Create and Update atributes takes only 2 seconds.

[image: Create]

Why is move (and probably copy + delete too) so slow?